# Elegant way to handle Python file read option rU in both py2 and py3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the best way to read a file using the read mode 'rU' (read a file with universal newline support) in an elegant way in Python 2 and 3? Py3.4 has recently deprecated this, causing DeprecationWarings:

```
with open(filename, 'rU') as handle:
    content = handle.read()
```

Comment: what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to call `open()` with a clever mix of arguments to make it work for both. I'd wrap it in a helper method which distinguishes between Python 2 and 3:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
   def open_text(filename):
       return open(filename, 'rU')
else:
   def open_text(filename):
       return open(filename, 'r', newline=None)
```

Comment: `r` mode and `newline=None`  are the defaults.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: true but `return open(filename)` looks a bit strange and will break if someone changes those defaults. I like to nail down the things that I absolutely need, also to document my intentions.

Comment: yep, fair enough, just thought it was worth mentioning that it is the default behaviour especially in relation to newline.